# Why does Chromium segfault when uploading images?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, chrome, segmentation-fault, snap

When selecting an image for upload, I am able to see the preview in the browser. Once the actual upload process begins, Chromium segfaults.

Seems like it's some sort of odd permission issue? The file I'm trying to upload, is an image I had previously downloaded from another page using "Save As...". The picture is stored in `/home/<username>/Pictures`. If I attempt to upload the image right away: segfault. However, if I open the image with Gimp, and simply select "Overwrite *.jpg" and exit. Then when I go back to the browser the image uploads just fine. Somehow overwriting the image with Gimp makes it so that it can be later uploaded.

When I run `ls -la` on the folder before and after that, the files are always owned by the same user have the same file access permissions, so I am unsure what is going on.

Running the snap installed version: 86.0.4240.183 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)

[image: segfault]

Comment: Do you have the permissions set to allow it to access it in your home folder? My usual suggestion is to find a .deb version/repository and install it the traditional way. But, you can check to see if you have the permission set to allow it.

Comment: In Ubuntu, doing:  `sudo apt install chromium-browser` automatically installs it from Snap :/

Comment: when I overwrite the file, its in the exact same folder as before, and when I check with `ls -la` before an after the permissions on the file are exactly the same

Comment: It's still possible (or was, with 20.04) to use a repo and install the traditional Chromium. It's just a search engine away. But, open up Ubuntu Software, click on installed, find Chromium, and the check the permissions. Snaps have their own permissions, accessed through the Ubuntu Software app.

Comment: Yeah, they were on by default, double checked, and it has the correct ones on :/

Comment: I am not at my right computer to test this, but [this link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/06/install-chromium-via-deb-ubuntu-20-04/) may interest you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

The solution is odd, you need to go into Ubuntu Software, select Chromium, then permissions. All permissions will be selected on by default. Oddly enough, if you flip off the ones file access, then turn them back on, it will magically work. If you get issues with you Chromium after this, toggle them on/again, and it will work.

Don't know why, but it just does...

---

This seems to be widespread enough, there are complaints about a new security "feature" causing this behaviour:

[image]